# Geolocation fails on Safari 11 consistently with POSITION_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: javascript, google-maps, safari, geolocation, maps

I have a pretty standard geolocation implementation I'm using in JavaScript.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function (position) {...}, 
    function (error) {....}
);
```

It is and has been working great on Internet Explorer/Chrome on my main Windows machine, physical Android, IOS on different iPhones...It's not working on my Macbook Pro with HighSierra and latest Safari though.

I downloaded an old version of Safari for Windows, and while I know it's old and deprecated, I figured I could at least see and it doesn't work on that either so I feel like that somewhat means something as far as testing goes.

The error code I'm getting back is POSITION_UNAVAILABLE. Here's where it gets really weird, I got so fed up because it really is on my end inexplicable, I decided to try other websites on Safari that have demo geolocation to test, html5demos.com, w3schools etc. All return same thing on Safari when debugging their code. Same thing with the older version of Safari for all tests on all websites on a completely different machine.

My site is HTTPS, I have confirmed location services are enabled on Safari for the website, I'm prompted for approve/deny location. I've confirmed all location services are active on the MBP system preferences. I have no idea what the heck is the deal, I can't confirm if...it's something...on this machine since it's my only MBP I have access to, but again it works on mobile IOS and every other website I've tried that has a Geolocation demo on the MBP does not as well on my Windows box with the last available version of Windows Safari 5.1.7. I'm using wifi if that matters at all since I've seen a hard connection for whatever reason coming up sometimes as a problem when consulting Google.

Any ideas?

Comment: Think I'm experiencing pretty much the same thing. HTTPS site, I get error code 2 = POSITION_UNAVAILABLE back on 3 out of 4 iOS devices. The other iOS device works fine. Also works on every desktop browser I've tried Mac & Windows. On the IOS devices that don't work, I'm not getting a prompt to allow location even in a private tab. On the IOS devices that don't work for my site they DO work on other tutorial sites.

Comment: The issue for me was neglecting to type https:// in front of the url of the webpage.

Comment: Same problem here, the site is https, getting POSITION_UNAVAILABLE on some devices, as usual all of my devices work, many at my client's don't work.